net.ifnames=0 disables PNIN fine on Debian Bullseye, but doesn't seem to on Debian Bookworm?
I'm trying to upgrade an embedded device from Debian Bullseye (v5.x) to Debian Bookworm (v6.x), where the (somewhat ancient) application running on top of it expects the Ethernet adapter to be eth0 (I know, I know). The kernel command line includes net.ifnames=0 (or else even Bullseye wouldn't work), but under Bookworm it's still ending up being called "eno1".
I've looked through the /etc/systemd/network/ scripts and the /usr/lib/udev/rules.d/ udev net rules, but I haven't noticed anything that seems related. Oh, and it's not a Dell (so no biosdevname=0 nonsense).
What have I missed? Or is it just not possible to map this to ethX any more?
